# Issue in adding passport based authentication of laravel 5.3 in my angular web app?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have added the passport based API authentication in my laravel API and trying to request from Angular webapp but there is a error saying that

> "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:"

calling to this route

> /user/api

**My route.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type,Authentication,Device,UID' );
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

});
```

**api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Comment: Shouldn't the request be to `/api/user`? Check the output of `artisan route:list`

Comment: I checked it . it is there with same route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what `route:list` should look with your current routes

```
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
```

So the correct route path is `/api/user` and **not** `/user/api` in fact every route defined in `api.php` will have the `/api` prefix as seen [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L69-L79).

Note that even if you call the correct path you might be redirected to `/login` which you don't have defined so you'll get the `NotFoundHttpException` error again.